# Sonarqube groups along with LDAP AD groups is over-riding all membership locally configured in SonarQube

Tags: active-directory, ldap, sonarqube, ldap-query

We are using LDAP plugin v1.4 & Sonarqube v4.5.7.

LDAP user configuration is working fine but if we enable group configuration it is overriding all membership locally configured in SonarQube including default local groups – sonar-users, sonar-administrators (these 2 groups are not available in Active Directory, practically tough to manage them in our LDAP setup). No new users are added to sonar-users group automatically and added users are removed when they login.

Because of this new users are not able to login to Sonar until admin configures his AD group ID he is part of in Sonar backend. Is there any solution to handle this?

Also, in this scenario,
1. Is there a way to exclude these 2 groups from AD syncup
2. How to add users automatically to sonar-users with AD group configuration

Our LDAP settings are stnadard settings available in LDAP plugin documentation.

Thanks a lot for any help on this topic.

Answer (score 2):

As [described in the docs](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/LDAP+Plugin#LDAPPlugin-GroupMapping) (emphasis added),

> **When group mapping is configured** (i.e the below ldap.group.* properties are configured), **membership in LDAP server will override any membership locally configured in SonarQube.** LDAP server becomes the one and only place to manage group membership (and the info is fetched each time the user logs in).

To turn group mapping off, remove the `ldap.group.*` properties.

Comment: Thanks for the response, Ann. 
But AD group configuration is required for us to manage project level security using AD group and this is saving us lot of time which otherwise will be spent in configuring individual users against each project. Configuring browse permission to ‘Anyone’ solves our problem but creates another problem that anyone can browse project without logging in which is not desired.

Comment: Is there a way to configure AD groups & retain sonar-users group (& adding users automatically to it) so that anyone can browse projects after logging in but view source code & administer only the projects for which AD group user is part of is configured.

Comment: Nope. You have to choose.